# Spring multi module: build a single war from multiple spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

We are having multiple spring-boot micro-services running independently. Now due to deployment constraints we need to build a big jar from all microservices.

So, this is what I've tried..

**In Parent pom:**

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<modules>
    <module>service-1</module>
    <module>service-2</module>
    .
    .
</modules>
```

**In service-1**

```
<artifactId>service-1</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

**In service-2**

```
<artifactId>service-2</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

But what is happening with this configuration is, maven is creating multiple war in each and every sub-modules, not a single war in the parent module parent.

So how to configure my parent pom to create a single war from all the sub-modules.

Note: In parent project I don't have spring-boot's main class, I am maintaining
only one `pom.xml` file

Comment: Which is exactly what you configured it to do. You have 2 projects each delivering a war file. If tha tis your setup and each has it seperate war file you probably need to do additional work to make that into a single war. Merging 2 projects, merge different xml files (`persistence.xml`), location of views etc. etc.

Comment: @M.Deinum, you mean to say,  maintain a monolithic structure?

Comment: That is what you at least need to merge to. That is also how you are deploying... You have microservices but apparently don't want that, hence you either need 1 big repo or merge it somehow and deliver an artificat. If there is no merging needed you can create regular `jar` files for the sub projects and create another project that uses those jars as dependencies and creates the war.

Comment: Shouldn't you try merging your code?
[https://medium.com/@eranda/combine-multiple-springboot-applications-into-a-single-application-649514e7a447] might help

Comment: @M.Deinum, for some clients, we still support micro-service deployment.

Comment: @M.Deinum we decided to merge the project. Management decided to support only monolithic build.